# How can increase root partition on KVM guest

Tags: linux, xfs

I have a kvm guest,as follow, The guest disk `/dev/vda` actually is a qcow2 file in Host

```
[root@guest ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

[root@guest ~]# uname -a
Linux guest 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 18 19:05:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@guest ~]# parted -l
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 64.4GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8590MB  8589MB  primary  xfs          boot
```

But I only see `8G` with `df`command, How can I increase the root partition to `64G`?  I have try `xfs_growfs /dev/vda1`, but doesn't work

```
[root@guest ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       8.0G  1.1G  6.9G  14% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   17M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this could be not related to virtualization at all.
I think you are using a single partition of 8GB on a 64GB disk, as reported by **`parted`**.

If you really need to enlarge that partition, then you'd run it to enlarge the one and only partition you have.
I normally use fdisk, not just for historical reasons. But with parted should be something like this:

```
parted /dev/vda1 resizepart 1 64G
```

Only later you'd run `xfs_growfs` to take advantage of the extra room.
As an option, you could run it interactively, issuing first a command to display sectors:

```
(parted) unit s
```

then a command to display the drive size in sectors (the actual size of the drive):

```
(parted) print
...
Disk /dev/vda: (the number of sectors here)
```

and finally the command to resize the partition #1 to that number.

If parted doesn't provide for a resize command, then you have only one option: you take note of the starting block number, partition type (primary), partition id (should be 83), then you delete the partition and recreate it with **exactly** the same starting block, type and ID, while the ending block is to be set as the last one available (as reported by the `parted` command).

As an option you could use `fdisk`, provided that the tool is available.
In that case you should run:

sudo fdisk /dev/vda

and give the command `p` in order to print the current partition table.
For example:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00070c95

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 218028031 218025984  104G 83 Linux
```

With `fdisk` you simply delete the partition and recreate it: it will propose you to make it as large as possible.

```
Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-234441647, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-234441647, default 234441647): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 111,8 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00070c95

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 234441647 234439600 111,8G 83 Linux
```

Then you'd issue a command `w` to write the changes to the disk.
A reboot is highly recommended before enlarging the file system.

Finally, I'd suggest you to use `df -H` instead of `df -h` so the numbers shown would match the ones by `parted -l`.

Comment: `parted /dev/vda1 resizepart 1 125829120` seem not work.  my parted version:`parted (GNU parted) 3.1`

Comment: @jython.li I added a few more details

Comment: Seem parted 3.1 can't use `resize` or `resizepart`  [How do I resize partitions and filesystems on them?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169395/how-do-i-resize-partitions-and-filesystems-on-them)

Comment: @jython.li I added some details to overcome that lack.

Comment: @jython.li Reword the question as it's not related to KVM or any virtualization environment. This is "generic" Linux system administration.

Comment: @jython.li If the solution is good for you, why not marking it as your favorite? After all, it's also the one and only so far! :-)